# truncate decimals after 2 places for double without decimal Format

Tags: java, performance, double, rounding

I am trying to "truncate" a double to return only two decimals places.

Example:
 given `1375568.13124765` would return => `1375568.13`

Using Decimal format is too slow. I am calling this multiple times in a loop. To speed up the process I am trying:

```
public static double castRoundTo2(double d)
{
  return (long) (d * 100 + 0.5) / 100.0;
}
```

This is returning something like `1375568.13000015`

Is there any was to cut off anything after two decimal places?

This is for numerical calculations.

Comment: If you're interested in *decimal* numbers, you'd be better off using `BigDecimal` to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any was to cut off anything after two decimal places?

That is what it does.

I would check your test

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(castRoundTo2(1375568.13000015));
    System.out.println(castRoundTo2(1375568.13124765));

    System.out.println(round2(-1375568.13000015));
    System.out.println(round2(-1375568.13124765));
}

public static double castRoundTo2(double d) {
    return (long) (d * 100 + 0.5) / 100.0;
}

public static double round2(double d) {
    return roundToFactor(d, 100);
}

public static double roundToFactor(double d, double f) {
    return Math.round(d * f) / f;
}
```

prints

```
1375568.13
1375568.13
-1375568.13
-1375568.13
```

Note: castRoundTo2 rounds to positive infinity. Math.round, rounds away from zero.

if you want a simple way to round you can do

Comment: Very helpful after looking back at my code I found the issue with in my test case. Thank you for creating you example.

Answer (score 2):

What do you hope to achieve by doing so? If you want to just display a decimal number nicely, one way you could do it is:

```
final double number = 45.212454664;
System.out.printf("%1.2f", number);
```

Which would print the number with 2 decimal places. In this case, the output is 45.21

Edit: If you want a general way to round numbers, you could do something like this:

```
    public static double round(final double number, final int precision){
    return Math.round(number * Math.pow(10, precision)) / Math.pow(10, precision);
}
```

Comment: This is the same as `System.out.printf("%.2f", number);`